# Intellij versioning (SVN / GIT) only ?

Tags: git, svn, intellij-idea, versioning

Is there a way to create an Intellij project for the purpose of only using its versioning tools only?

Meaning, I have a folder, could be anything, java, files, whatever. I want to create a new project and import that and let intellij discover the repository and let me take actions on it. Doesn't not need to compile, be run, sdk, or what not.

Right now, I am unable to figure out how to do this. Import or new project only lists Framework stuff, but I see "Empty Project" but no files turns up in the navigator.

Is this possible!?

Answer (score 0):

Ook, I seem to have solved this by creating a new "Static Web Project" ... everything seems to get in without issues an svn is recognized.

Perhaps a new "Static Folder Project" would help make things easier for the future...

Comment: Intellij is an IDE, not a version control UI.

Comment: I know, but once your files are in there, it can be used as a version control tool, is a shame to not to use it when it is better than most other tools, so how can I get my files there was my question... I answered it too ;)

Comment: Yes, but that’s why there is no (and never will be a) `Static Folder Project`. But if your answer solved your question, feel free to accept it :).

Comment: I can do that first tomorrow :) I don't see why there wouldn't a need to make it easier to use an IDEA for stuff like that, even if its not for versioning. Editing text files or what not might be useful at occasion. Anyhow, don't say never to a useful feature, it doesn't really cost anything to add such a feature and would make it easier for many. I have wanted to do things like that since ages, and always struggle what type of project structure one should choose.